# Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have an installation of Laravel on Wampserver. The directory is as follows:

C:\wamp\www\laravel

Now URLs are like this:

`http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/home/index`

So I used the following htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -indexes
DirectoryIndex index.PHP
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.PHP|images|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_ FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_ FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L, QSA]
```

To reduce the URL to

`http://localhost/laravel/public/home/index`

But the laravel framework insists that all application files reside in the public folder.

So I would like to know what I need to add to (or subtract from) the htaccess file so that the URL can look like

`http://localhost/laravel/home/index`

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When testing locally I do one of two things.

1. Create a new .htaccess below the public directory with the following.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on

       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Create a new virtual host. With WAMP you can navigate to `C:\wamp\bin\apache\YOUR APACHE VERSION\conf\extra` and find your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file, in there you can see example virtual hosts. Here's one of mine:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public"
       ServerName laravel.dev
       ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   Make sure that your vhosts configuration file is being included. Open up your `httpd.conf` file and search for the `vhosts` file, uncomment the include line if it's commented out. Then I open the CLI and enter `notepad "C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"` which opens up your hosts file. Underneath the item that mentions `localhost` place your new host. Here's an example.

   ```
   127.0.0.1  laravel.dev
   ```

   Make sure you restart Apache and bingo, you should be able to navigate to `http://laravel.dev` and you won't have any annoying public directory. This is how I achieve it, as I prefer the nicer looking virtual host rather then a long winded `localhost` URL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it but doing `http://laravel.dev` just took me to the wamp's index.

There's another method that I'm using: Moving the contents of the public folder and then modifiying the index file and changing the require path like so:
`require './paths.php';` 
Of course, I would not do this during deployment but its a quick way   to start

Comment: Collapsing the folders turned out to be a bad idea. I finally figured a work around. For some reason, Your procedure didn't work for me.

Comment: I remember doing everything step but it kept showing me wamp's index page. I got the method that I finally used from a site and there, the instruction only added the vhosts settings for the new virtual host that you wanted to create. and it produced the same problem only that this time, it overshadowed the localhost's vhost. Hence my adding a vhost config for the www folder

Comment: I now see why it didn't work. Because the `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is commented by default in the `conf/httpd.conf`, the changes I made to the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file had no effect.

Comment: What do you mean, when you say "Create a new .htaccess below" ? Inside the public folder or in the laravel folder?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann Below meaning outside the folder, so next to the `readme.md` and `composer.json` files.

Comment: Take me for hours because I didn't move the .htaccess file out........Thanks Anyway, and Please explain it explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured a way out. First of all, I had to open and edit my Apache httpd.conf by selecting it from the Wamp Aestran tray menu. The I had to uncomment the line

`#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

After that, I opened the file which is located at the

`<wampdirectory>/bin/apache/apache.x.y.z/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

then I added the following lines.

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        #If you want to allow access from your internal network
        # For specific ip addresses add one line per ip address
        #Allow from 192.168.0.100
        # For every ip in the subnet, just use the first 3 numbers of the subnet
        #Allow from 192.168.0
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

## must be first so the the wamp menu page loads when you use just localhost as the domain name

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/sites/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/sites/laravel/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        #If you want to allow access from your internal network
        # For specific ip addresses add one line per ip address
        #Allow from 192.168.0.100
        # For every ip in the subnet, just use the first 3 numbers of the subnet
        #Allow from 192.168.0
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The next step was to edit my hosts file at C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

and added

`127.0.0.1 laravel.dev`

Then restarted Wamp and it worked. Thanks to you guys for pointing me in the right direction. Really Appreciate it

Comment: this is the solution that I posted and recommended you use. Although I did neglect to mention that vhosts are not included automatically in your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Wow... Thanks very much, you really saved me

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I got this working on my local dev environment was to do the following:

(Assuming you have WAMP installed in C:\WAMP)

Create the following folder:

```
c:\wamp\www\laravel
```

Download laravel and put the contents in the above directory. You will know you have done it right if you can browse to hxxp://localhost/laravel/public and get the opening screen. However, this isn't good enough. We want to get that screen by going to `http://localhost/laravel`

So then we do the following:

Create a textfile containing the following:

```
Alias /laravel "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public" 

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/laravel/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Save this file as `laravel.conf` in the c:\wamp\alias directory.

Finally, restart your wampserver.

You should now be able to surf to `http://localhost/laravel`

Note that the above is strictly for a local development environment.

Comment: @gangaraju They're not typos. They're that way to indicate that they're not URLs you should click on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hxxp

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna end up with your code and your public folder residing in the same place, which most people do not recommend. I'd suggest you take advantage of using a local web server.

Why not make `mysite.dev` point to `laravel/public` directory so you could just use `http://mysite.dev` everytime, you have cleaner and shorter URL's too?

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to do it this way I.e. putting application files in a public folder strictly for testing and learning purposes. Its exhausting to go through all that config every new test project. Also, Wampserver has Apache's configuration all mangled. For instance, I can't find the conf.d directory

Answer (score 0):

As a newb to WAMP and Laravel, I struggled at bit but did get the virtualhost thing to work on my WIN7PRO 64-bit box.  In WAMPSERVER/Apache/hppd.conf at the end of the file, I added:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot C:/webapp/public
 ServerName webapp
 <Directory C:/webapp/public >
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from All
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www
 ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

and I added:

127.0.0.1 webapp

to the hosts file.  (I was never successful editing the vhosts files, as many posts on the web suggested.)

These changes allow me to get to my Laravel test app in my browser via

```
http://webapp
(and also, via just http://127.0.0.1)
```

and, to get to all my other sites, via:

```
http://localhost/devsite/whatever..
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it but I kept getting a "Forbidden Error" Message.