# How to: make my routes start working with Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new in Laravel (v4.0.5) and according the website http://laravel.com/docs/routing and other book I found, make a route its as easy as this

```
Route::any('foo', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

so, I try at my host

```
http//myhost/public/foo
```

(and I have to use **/public** due if i only enter to my host directly where is the folder, I see the structure of the framework... anybody know why is that?)

But I get **not found**

I've tried

```
Route::any('user','UserController@index');
```

I have created my controller like this

```
<?php

class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
    {
        return View::make('users');
    }

    public function getIndex() 
    {
        return View::make('users');
    }
}
```

And tried with `/users` but nothing...

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going here:

```
http://myhost/public/index.php/foo
```

You will need to setup URL rewrites if you want it to work with

```
http://myhost/public/foo
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you!! it works like that!! why is that? how can I solve it to dont dont have to write the index.php ??

Comment: It's because your first URL is searching for a foo directory within the public directory, it does not know the request needs to be processed through the index.php file. In order to get it to work without using index.php you'll need to configure some URL rewrites in Apache (either through .htaccess file or apache config file). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel

Comment: ive tried with apache but no results, i will try with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You should point the web root of your server to the `public` folder. If you're using Apache, you can change this on the `httpd.conf` file, looking for `DocumentRoot` setting. Example:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Raphael\Documents\GitHub\RaphStore\public"
```

This is important because it makes sure no one has access to your project files, as it should be.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will have to create the rule then, but, any idea about the routes?