# How to configure DocumentRoot to use with Laravel 4?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-4, bitnami, document-root

I have an apache local server (installed through BitNami) and I want to configure the DocumentRoot so that I can access to my Laravel app when I go to localhost instead of the BitNami default page.

Here is my httpd.conf (included also the settings for clean URL's):

```
DocumentRoot "C:/BitNami/wappstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs/my_project/public"

<Directory "C:/BitNami/wappstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/BitNami/wappstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/htdocs/my_project/public">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And here the my_project/public/.htaccess file which comes with Laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've restarted apache everytime I made a change but I always get the BitNami default page when going to localhost so, what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

----- Edit -----
I've just achieve it with another approach found here: [Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)