# Laravel Routing URLs not working except for default URI

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have set up Laravel 5 for the first time on my localhost. I am able to load the default URL but not any others. In other words, this works:

`localhost/laravel/siteName/public/`

but not

`localhost/laravel/siteName/home/` or `localhost/laravel/siteName/public/home/`.

I have not changed any default values in `routes.php` or in `.htaccess`.

I did try adding

```
Rewritebase /laravel/siteName/public/
```

to .htaccess but that did not solve the problem.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help.

Comment: How have you set up your webserver? Have you used something like http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead or http://puphpet.com ?

Comment: @wiesson I am not using homestead. I am using the basic implementation of WAMP, Apache 2.4.9.

Comment: I'd recommend that you make use of [VirtualHosts](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-virtual-hosts-in-a-wamp-server/), as working in a sub-directory on localhost is not recommended.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the subdirectories. The default installation of Laravel 5 assumes that it is served from root (in this case localhost). When I reinstalled Laravel as root everything worked correctly. Instead of setting up Virtual Hosts I just switch out symlinks from a different directory to manage the various sites I am working on.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this help but lets give it a go:

1. In your commandline/terminal cd to your laravel project root
2. Run `php artisan serve` (don't close this window or the server closes)
3. Go to http://localhost:8000/ -> This should return the view set. For example:

   Route::get('/', function()
           {
               return view('index.php');
           });

That's it. Try to register some other routes and go to them at localhost:8000/your-route

Please comment or add more details about your webserver and other setup if this doesn't help.

Comment: When I run `php artisan run` I get `[InvalidArgumentException] \n Command "run" is not defined. \n Did you mean this? \n schedule:run`

Comment: Whoopsie, my bad. Double checked and the correct command is `php artisan serve` . You might also want to remove that rewrite rule you added from the .htaccess.

Comment: @MartinJH - It runs fine but why?, before i run all my laravel apps without using `php artisan serve`.

Comment: @151291 - It runs because you have booted up a php server. Could uoi run your laravel apps without one before? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @MartinJH - i am using xampp, all my apps runs fine after start xampp. i did not use `php artisan serve` before.

Comment: @151291 - Xamp is also capable of running a php server, so that's why it worked before. I can't tell why it stopped working though.

Comment: @MartinJH - I solved this without using `php artisan` command, project should not contain subfolder and project file name should not have space.