# Laravel project from artisan to apache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was running  laravel project in my developpement machine under artisan on port 8000, now I need to move it to production server(ubuntu) which is configured under apache, I would like to now changes to make to my project so as to work perfectly.

Comment: rtfm.. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration I use for most of my projects (However it can be done in other different ways)

put the contents of the `public` directory of your laravel project dist folder inside apache's `public_html` or `www` directory (**/var/www/html/** in **Ubuntu 14.04**

Put the rest of your laravel files (everything except the public folder) outside public_html (recommended for security reasons - especially in production) - the structure will look something like this on Ubuntu 14.04

```
- /var/www/
    - laravel
        app
        bootstrap
        ...
    - html
        index.php
        css
        ...
```

Change a few values:

Inside **index.php**: change

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'`

to

`require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php'`

and

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`

Inside your **laravel/bootstrap/paths.php** file:

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'`
to
`'public' => __DIR__.'/../../html'`

Make sure the .htaccess file is there and if the default .htaccess file is causing problems replace its contents with:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And make sure you have write permission to **laravel/app/storage** folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your project will not need any changes. You just need to setup the proper apache2 virtual host

Most importantly make sure that you set the DocumentRoot to your public folder.