# Laravel - best solution for removing /public from URL

Tags: url, laravel

What is the best practise and best solution for removing /public path from URL in Laravel 5?

Comment: apache rewrite_mod and .htaccess files are your friends.

Comment: I would like to see whole solution, not just advice.

Comment: There is no url, no explaination about your dir structure...You did not even try to do it! stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. Take a look at the [apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), everything you need is explained. OR just search other questions, you are not the only one to ask this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)

Comment: How Laravel is doing it when i use "artisan serve"? Is he changing the root to '/public'?

Comment: However, you don't need to use rewriting for php's internal web server, because it is only for testing purpose. Your question is not related to php nor laravel, it is web-server-related / url-rewriting-related. SO depending on your production web server you should find the most appropriated way to achieve this.

Comment: That is what i am looking for, Laravel is using some method to achieve exactly, what i am looking for, can you help me with it?

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with this solution.

Make a folder for all laravel files, for example 'web'.

Take everything from '/public' path and move to the root of the web (you can delete '/public' folder). So your structure will look like this.

```
-- .htaccess
-- index.php
-- favicon.ico
-- ... another stuff from '/public'
  -- web
    -- /app
    -- /config
    -- .. all laravel stuff
```

Then just edit your index.php

replace this :

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

with this :

```
require __DIR__.'/web/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/web/bootstrap/app.php';
```

That is working and probably the best method, what you can find.

Comment: No this is the worst method.

Comment: What is the best method then?

Comment: Point your server to public. Don't play with secure structure. Your http visitors has nothing to do with your code. Just give them your assets and index

Comment: Have you got something for communicating, like Skype? I would like to ask something, i will pay you.