# Laravel not posting

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5

I'm using Localhost and for some reason my laravel site isn't posting (latest version). When I hit the submit button it refreshes with GET data in the URL. I don't believe it hits store function. 
I'm accessing the form in the create function where it should be sent to the store function.

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostsController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
        {{Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
        {{Form::textarea('body', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])}}
    </div>
    {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
```

This code doesn't appear to post as it leaves the following in the address bar

```
/posts/create?_token=kfXL2i4aiRdHiCHFwMJUkb3JMDx0OREcCeeDTY9p&title=&body=TEST
```

I also tried alternatively with the following

```
<form action="PostsController@store.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="body">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Which leaves the following in the address bar

```
/posts/create?title=&body=
```

My Web Route is

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

My Controller is the generated with composer. The below is the store method.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);

    return "TEST";
}
```

Comment: Which local environment are you using? if you put dd("test") in the top of the store method it prints?

Comment: Wamp, forgot to mention

Comment: And it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Did you have any instance with laravel post request working? I would follow these steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487122/6329802 Update with news so maybe we can help

Comment: Hey, No this is my first attempt at posting. I have already set it up within the public folder with a server name ect

Comment: IMHO the problem is the .htaccess try the first solution from linked answer

Comment: I have tried adding it but it keeps crashing the server will a internal 500

Comment: the best solution restart the project again, your files are messed.

Comment: Hi, I don't really want to start all over again as I will end up in the same place

Comment: <form action="PostsController@store.php" method="post"> is not a valid way to set action for a form. store is a function not a file with .php extension!

Comment: Yeah, That was just a test the official is the other form.

Comment: The best or worst side of laravel , rails is you dont know how it works but it does. So i always prefer to write code which could be always in my control. Why don't you try it like. Use Html Form Tag, Ofcourse you will need csrf token, Use Route::get/ Route::Post instead of Route::Resource and things like these.

Comment: In your first example are you closing the form with Form::close() ? Also can try setting the action to route name "photos.store".

Comment: Hi, Yeah the forms being closed. I have tried changing the roots from resource to post and get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your form really is POSTing, and hitting the `store` method, where your validation fails.  When validation fails, it redirects (with a GET request) back to the route where the POST came from - which I'm guessing is `posts/create`, as standard.

Check your browser's dev tools, network tab - you should see the post and redirect happening.  As a quick test to confirm, try commenting our your validation in the `store` method.  You should also display your validation errors (which would explain what is going on here) - more info in [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) on how to do that.

Comment: I removed the validation and I added "return view('posts.show');" to the store but still has the get command.

Comment: Don't add another point of failure until you understand the problem.  Remove what you added (`return view('posts.show');`), just leave `return "TEST";` - do you see TEST?  What do your browser dev tools show?

Comment: Hi, I tried it with Test again but no luck. Looking into the Dev tools I can't see a post.

Comment: Are there any other forms on the page? Is there any Javascript involved?

Comment: No other forms on the page and no JS used

Comment: In dev tools, do you have `Preserve Log` on in the network tab?  A POST followed by a redirect GET will happen fast, and unless you are preserving the log to show all requests the POST will disappear very quickly and be replaced by the GET.  I can't see a way a plain HTML form with POST would not POST.  Laravel has nothing to do with that ... Is the rendered HTML in your browser (view source) OK?

Comment: Yeah that's what I did and it's strange as I have never encountered this before. I used both a plain form and the laravel creative.

Comment: Other than the css and fonts the only doc I get is "http://local.build/posts/create?_token=9w9v3zOo0EvBGwShteKz1EiWDAx0c6yYZYqMpEZt&title=&body="

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your form action with just the url? Action='posts'

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dd($request);` to store method and see what comes back as output.

Comment: Added it to the function and nothing came back

Comment: Do you have the route set up in the web.php routes list? Maybe try changing the action to /posts or whatever URL you have configured.