# Preventing laravel from accepting index.php in the URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Having used `Route::get('/', ContnameController@methodName`, how can I make Laravel (5.8 and above) show its default 404 page when `myapp/index.php` is used in the address bar?
In another word: How can I prevent Laravel from showing a file with *.php* extension when an alternative Route is used to access the same file?

Apache Mod Rewrite is enabled and there is no problems related to it. Everything related to it works fine and all requests are directed to index.php as expected. I only do not want the user to use `myapp/index.php`instead of what I define in `Route::get('/',...`. Laravel seems to treat both interchangeably!

This is not a duplicate of Apache Mod rewrite question. Now the default (out of the box) Laravel home page is pulled from `welcome.blade.php` and is accessed via `laravelapp/` as per the default `Route::get('/', ..`. But that same page is also accessible via `laravelapp/index.php`. Is that an expected and accepted behavior if you do not want extensions in your app URLs? Obviously, if this is undesired behavior, then the Apache Mod rewrite is not the culprit even if there is an .htaccess fix.

Comment: You need to enable rewrite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel

Comment: It is enabled and works fine in all other cases that relate to rewrite mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Mod Rewrite For Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448912/apache-mod-rewrite-for-laravel)

Comment: It has nothing to do with Apache Mod Rewrite. Please do not rush to link an issue to another without enough understanding of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a rewrite rule, an apache example would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R=404]
```

Another way is to add something like below in one of your service providers:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // ...
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Str::endsWith(Arr::get($_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', ''), 'index.php')) {
           abort(404);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The first suggestion resulted in showing Apache default **Not Found** error page. The second got Whoops! to throw `FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'App\Providers\Str' not found`. Is is possible to configure it to show Laravel default 404 page?

Comment: `Str` needs `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` at the top of the file after the namespace. `Arr` may also need `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

Comment: YES! Now it works as I wanted it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your `public\.htaccess` file just after `RewriteEngine On` line

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php[^/] /$1? [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2? [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This resulted in omitting the `index.php` from the address bar, but redirected the request to the home page. What I try to do is getting it to show the Laravel 404 default (or custom) page. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible but in this case you have to redirecte to another url where you can call you custom error template

Comment: I tried hard to come up with a way to do something like that before I bother good people with questions, but I just couldn't do it the correct way. If possible, please give me the steps. Grateful for the responses.